# Show/hide standard component fields on Salesforce Communty based on Record Type of other field?

Tags: community, record-type, partner-communities, field-level-security

We would like to show/hide specific fields on our Salesforce Community based on the Record Type selected. The user will have the same security profile, so using FLS doesn't solve our problem.

For example, let's assume we are using the Contact object. A Record Type may be Patient, and if patient is selected, then I want to show the Patient NPI field. If a different record type is selected, I don't want to show that field.

This can be done easily with page layouts in the Salesforce UI, but I don't see a way to do this in the Salesforce Community standard record detail page/component.

Is it possible to do what I need via configuration or will we need to develop custom Lightning Components to do this?

Comment: Man- standard record detail works in community same way as in Salesforce internally. You just need to assign target layouts to community profile.

Answer (score 2):

Standard record detail Page in community is determined from page layout assigned for current user profile on given record type. So regardless it's community or salesforce, standard detail Page displays fields based on assigned Page layouts.

However, in community, there are different components for each unit of page layout.

- Highlight Panel on page layout determines what displays in the Record Headline component.
- Record Headline: Displays the record name and key record highlights along with buttons to edit and delete the record.
- Record Information: Displays all record details including related records and the record feed. It also allows users to create new related records and post to the record feed.

Here is detail explanation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_designer_create_record_detail_page.htm&type=5